# PresentViewController erroring from Nav Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UINavigationController` subclass that I want to have redirect to a sign-in page if the user isn't signed in. In the `viewdidload()` I have:

```
if(AppUser == nil){
    var SignIn: AnyObject! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController("SignInView") as! SignInViewController
    self.pushViewController(SignIn, animated: false)
}
```

`AppUser` is linked to an `NSUserDefaults` object. `SignInViewController` is an actual class and `SignInView` is the StoryBoardID of my desired ViewController. When I put all of this code into the `viewDidLoad()` it errors on the first line with:

```
"Cannot invoke 'instantiateViewController' with argument of list type '(String)'"
```

On the second line it says:

```
"Cannot invoke 'pushViewController' with an argument list of type '(Anyobject!, animated: Bool)'"
```

What am I doing it wrong? Does it have something to do with running this from a `UINavigationController` instead of a `UIViewController`?

Comment: Separate point but you shouldn't be pushing view controllers in `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear:` because it will mess up your view hierarchy. You need to make sure the transition in progress has fully completed before presenting something else.

Comment: you shouldn't need to asign `AnyObject` to `SignIn` just do
`var SignIn = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController("SignInView") as! SignInViewController`

Comment: It's also good form to start variable names with lower case letters. Uppercase is generally reserved for classes, structs, and global variables.

Comment: I didn't assign anyobject

Comment: You have `var SignIn: AnyObject!`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that `self` indicates your `UINavigationViewController`.

For your question, I think you need to change this line of code:

```
var SignIn: AnyObject! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController("SignInView") as! SignInViewController
```

into this:

```
if let signInViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController("SignInView") as? SignInViewController {
    // handle your sign-in view controller
}
```

I changed this because you indicated that `SignIn` is an `AnyObject!`. When you are dealing with **Swift**, you have to be very clear that what `?` and `!` mean. BTW, naming convention is important as well.

Comment: he will probably have to use `self.storyboard?` or `self.storyboard!`

Comment: Not really, as long as he can handle it well from instantiation. The second error message indicated that the type is not correct at all. That's why we don't need to specify the type `AnyObjects!`

Comment: Not talking about that. `self.storyboard` is an optional.

Comment: Oh oh oh, get it. I was just aware that. Thanks for letting me know. @boidkan. But, error turns out to be adding `AnyObject!`

Comment: Yes I know, I wasn't saying it wasn't :) Look at the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` instead of `instantiateViewController`.

So for example

```
if(AppUser == nil){
    var signIn = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInView") as! SignInViewController
    self.pushViewController(SignIn, animated: false)
}
```

You should also removed `AnyObject!` from `var SignIn: AnyObject!`. Also I uncapitalized signIn for better programming practice. It's up to you if you want to do this or not.

It is also good practice to do what Lucas did in his answer by unwrapping

```
if let signIn = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInView") as? SignInViewController{
    self.pushViewController(SignIn, animated: false)
}
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions :)